# htaccess is not working on 1and1 server

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using ci in my project and i have uploaded it on 1and1 server but htaccess is not working there.
URL's are not working withouit index.php. you can see in the given link.

http://reviewwatchdog.co.uk/demo/reviewwatchdog/index.php/home/risk_list

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

add line

`RewriteBase /`

i had same problem , that worked for me.